# Accessing Global Set Variable

Tags: globals

Just starting to play with Craft going to be a learning curve coming from wp and processwire etc.

I created a custom Global Set and called it Logo which I assumed I could use in the _layout.html template to show a logo in the header and make it easy to change etc.

I called the set Logo and it has a handle of logo. This created the Globals option in the top nav. Here I was able to upload a logo from my assets etc.

Now in the _layout.html template I am trying to access this image by using the following but nothing shows up.

```
<img src="{{ Logo.logo }}">
```

Based on the docs it says:
You can access your Global Sets from any template via their handles. For example, if you have a Global Set with the handle “companyInfo”, and it has a field with the handle “yearEstablished”, you can access that field anywhere using this code:

{{ companyInfo.yearEstablished }}

I also tried

```
<img src="{{ Logo.logo.url() }}">
```

What am I doing wrong am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image fields are an array, because you can have multiple images within that field. Usually you would loop through the array to output your images:

```
{% if Logo.logo | length %}
    {% for image in Logo.logo %}
        {{ image.url }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Or, if you only have a single image in the array, you can just do this:

```
{% set image = Logo.logo.first() %}

{% if image %}
    {{ image.url }}
{% endif %}
```

More info on Asset templating [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields#templating)

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that as well and it wasn't working. It's always empty so it doesn't get past the if statement.

Comment: Make sure you are using the globalSet handle and not the title. I would guess that it is all lowercase. `{{ logo.logo.first.url }}`

Comment: Thank you that was it, Looking back I read the docs wrong and thought I was supposed to use the Global Set Name.Handle but now I know its globalSetHandle.FieldName thanks for help much appreciated. Really liking craft so far.